# Java coding style related questions

Tags: java, java-8, coding-style

Hello I need some inputs with regards to the following two questions

1> This is the following object which I receive as a request input

```
public class CreatePaymentRequestDto {
    long insuranceId; 
    int annualCalculationYear; 
    int annualCalculationTotal; 
    int annualPayment; //
    int oneTimePayment;
    int manualChangePayment;
    boolean createRefund;
}
```

but when Transferring it within my service I want to keep the other fields intact except the insuranceId needs to be Insurance object itself .. what would be good coding style instead of creating another DTO such as below

```
public class CreatePaymentDto {
    Insurance insurance; 
    int annualCalculationYear; 
    int annualCalculationTotal; 
    int annualPayment; //
    int oneTimePayment;
    int manualChangePayment;
    boolean createRefund;
}
```

2> The second question is about interfaces for services ..

If we have a Main service class and other service classes with a single project ,  few of them are sub classes of this Main service class and a few other offer different services .. is it a good design practice to create interfaces between these service classes within a single project .. The question rather is when is it a good idea to create interfaces ?

Thanks

Comment: Make a class for the other int/boolean parameters. It depends on your unit test support for these services; no support means probably interfaces. _In this case I certainly do not want to give a too strong advice, given varying practices/contexts like JPA._

Answer (score 0):

Having two classes for the purpose you describe isn't necessarily bad. Rather than complicating things, you have two classes with names suggesting their purpose of existence, one indicates it is a request, other indicates it is a transfer object. It will also allow you to change your internal design and requests independently.

I'm not sure I fully understood the second part about interfaces for service classes. Personally when deciding to create an interface, I use some simple guidelines:

1: Use interfaces to abstract behaviour or functionality

2: Does this behaviour vary.

3: Is this interface used as a contract

Example: consider the behaviour of writing data. Lets define an interface

```
interface DataWriter {
 void write()
}
```

Now you can define one or more implementations of this to specify multiple behaviours depending on the requirements.

If you are not going to need to have multiple behaviours ever, you might not need an interface.

If you are designing classes which communicate, and if multiple developers are working on them, having an interface makes things easier by acting as a contract for communication.